# Package with buttons automatically added to standard layout upon installation

Tags: apex, managed-package

I have a package that contains some custom buttons - I'd like these buttons automatically added to the 4 standard layouts upon installation (Lead, Contact, Account, and Opportunity). Whats the best way to do this, custom post-install apex code? What would the method-call look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved within ant and shell script.

- retrieve all layouts you're interested with
- add section with custom button name
- deploy layouts back

Custom button are situated in the very beginning of layout:

```
Opportunity-Opportunity Layout.layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<customButtons>QTCC</customButtons>
```